# JPanel height does not update immediately

Tags: java, swing

I'm using the following code to add an image to a JPanel inside of a JScrollPane.  I want the scroll pane to scroll to the bottom, but it doesn't seem to recognize that an image has been added until awhile later, even though I am calling this inside a SwingUtilities wrapper.

```
private void addImage(final String image){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imagePanel.addImage(image);
            final JScrollBar vScroll = imageScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vScroll.setValue(vScroll.getMaximum());
        }
    });
}
```

The addImage code from imagePanel looks like this:

```
public void addImage(String image){
        System.out.println("Pre-height: " + getHeight());
        add(createImageLabel(image));
        System.out.println("After-height: " + getHeight());
        revalidate();
        System.out.println("Revalidate-height: " + getHeight());
    }
```

It looks like this results in the following, for example:

```
Pre-height: 690
After-height: 690
Revalidate-height: 690
```

If I sleep in a loop after the call, it seems to take about 200 ms for the height to actually change.

The code I have here always ends up 1 image behind when scrolling.  What's the best way to go about scrolling to the bottom in such a way that I actually know where the bottom is?  I am only a little familiar with Swing conventions, but I thought that since everything was happening inside a SwingUtilities call, it would know what it was doing.

Full Executable Code Example that demonstrates the problem:

```
package com.foo.bar

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ScrollImageExampleFrame extends JFrame{

    private ScrollImageExamplePanel siePanel;

    public ScrollImageExampleFrame(){
        setSize(1024, 768);
        siePanel = new ScrollImageExamplePanel();
        getContentPane().add(siePanel);
    }

    class ScrollImageExamplePanel extends JPanel {
        ImageViewExamplePanel imagePanel = new ImageViewExamplePanel();
        JScrollPane imageScrollPane = new JScrollPane(imagePanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        public ScrollImageExamplePanel(){
            setLayout(new MigLayout("nogrid"));
            imageScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 0));
            add(imageScrollPane, "east, width 300!, height 100%");
        }

        private void addImageOuter(final String image){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imagePanel.addImageInner(image);
                    imagePanel.revalidate();
                    final JScrollBar vScroll = imageScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                    vScroll.setValue(vScroll.getMaximum());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class ImageViewExamplePanel extends JPanel {
        public ImageViewExamplePanel() {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        }

        public void addImageInner(String image){
            URL imageUrl = ImageViewExamplePanel.class.getResource("/com/foo/bar/" + image);
            ImageIcon ii = resizeImage(imageUrl, 360, 270);
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(ii);
            add(label);
            revalidate();
        }

        private ImageIcon resizeImage(URL url, int x, int y){
            Image image = null;
            try{
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
                Image newImage = image.getScaledInstance(x, y, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                return new ImageIcon(newImage);
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScrollImageExampleFrame frame = new ScrollImageExampleFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.siePanel.addImageOuter("foo.png");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        frame.siePanel.addImageOuter("foo.png");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        frame.siePanel.addImageOuter("foo.png");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        frame.siePanel.addImageOuter("foo.png");        
    }

}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE, as demonstration you can to put there empty JPanel

Comment: UGH.  MY SSCCE works how I would expect.  I don't want to paste the entire project in here, but I can't pin down why my project is seeing a delay between adding the image and updating the height.  Still trying to produce a SSCCE.

Comment: Why are you creating a new JLabel. Just use `label.setIcon( new ImageIcon() );`. Avoiding adding/removing components on a visible GUI when an easier alternative exists.

Comment: The component contains multiple images and can have more added to it.  I am creating a new label for each image that is added, but the old labels stay as well, because I still want to display those images.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far.  I added a full code example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next trick for that purpose:

```
private void addImage(final String image){
    imagePanel.addImage(image);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final JScrollBar vScroll = imageScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vScroll.setValue(vScroll.getMaximum());
        }
    });
}
```

In that case all components will be added,validated and painted, and then in `invokeLater` you can change position of `JScrollBar`. It helps you.

Comment: This seems like it should definitely work, but I'm still seeing the wrong height at the time that vScroll.getMaxmimum() is executed.

Comment: Call `revalidate()` method of `JFrame` in which you show your `JScrollPane`, it recalculate size of panel.

Comment: Thank you, alex2410, this ended up being my problem!

Answer (score 0):

@alex2410 identified a solution - By calling revalidate() on the containing JFrame, my component sizes were correctly calculated when I needed them. I was able to fix my sample code by replacing the addImageOuter method as follows:

```
    private void addImageOuter(final String image){
        final JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imagePanel.addImageInner(image);
                frame.revalidate();
                final JScrollBar vScroll = imageScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                vScroll.setValue(vScroll.getMaximum());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this...

```
imagePanel.updateUI();
```

Comment: -1, there is no need to use updateUI(). The method is used by Swing on a LAF change.